# Shell scripting in Python: calling programs that use curses, etc

Tags: python, shell, scripting, subprocess, stdout

Here's a very specific question, but I'm looking for a *slightly more general solution*:

I'm writing a shell script in Python to assist in various config tasks, including performing a `git clone` of various repositories.  When I call `git clone`, is there a good way for me to supply git display output directly to the terminal (progress bars, etc)?

Just piping the subprocess's stdout to sys.stdout doesn't cut it, because `git`'s behavior involves re-writing over the same portion of the terminal to indicate progress.  So this isn't really good enough:

```
import sys, subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen("git clone --recursive https://github.com/my/repo.git",
                           shell=True,
                           stdout=sys.stdout,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I'm not looking for the answer "use *git-python*" -- rather, I'm looking for a more general technique that I can apply to this and other config tasks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import os
os.system(mycommand)
```

This works for `wget`, the progress-bar that rewrites itself on one line on the screen works correctly this way. I suppose it would work for `git` and others as well.